# What is an arch based distribution that moves slower

Tags: arch-linux, distribution-choice

What's an arch based distro that updates slower? The frequent updates of the main repository are a bit too fast for my taste. I like the rolling release system so want to keep that.

Comment: Debian sid, probably.

Comment: @jasonwryan - is that sarcasm? I can't tell.

Comment: @mikeserv It works either way...

Comment: @jasonwryan - that's what I meant - I had a chuckle.

Comment: Arch LTS [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Enhance_system_stability)

Comment: @bdowning may as well post that as an answer.

Comment: Doesn't lts only apply to the kernel and modules? What about the user space packages (gnome, vim, gcc, gawk, grep, libc etc..)

Comment: So you *don't* want a rolling release then? The definition of rolling release is to update each component as soon as it's available.

Comment: @Giles: I want to keep the rolling release system but with less frequent updates.

Comment: Use [Manjaro](https://manjaro.org)! It is an Arch derivative, works essentially the same, with many subtle and a few obvious differences, existing only to cover Arch's lack of user-friendliness. Also uses its own repos, and supports the AUR. Has an unstable repo delivering Arch's packages after its release by a day or two. Has a **stable** repo that tests Arch's packages and patches them if necessary. This, however, lags a few weeks after Arch, but that's probably what you want. [Full list of differences](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Manjaro:_A_Different_Kind_of_Beast).

Answer (score 2):

If it's a rolling-release that's not so bleeding-edge you're after, take a good look at [Tumbleweed](https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Tumbleweed) from OpenSuse.

Arch is generally intended to be a pure upstream system, and as such is pretty bleeding-edge. [Antegros](http://antergos.com/) and [Manjaro](https://manjaro.github.io/) are Arch based systems that can lag a week or so behind, but that's probably not what you're after.